# connection to internet via DUN?

Tags: linux, networking

I am using embedded linux, I have got DUN Phone identified as /dev/rfcomm0.

Now I want to establish Internet connection through it, Can you please help me on how to do it?

My embedded linux is just, kernel + file system, running Qt for embedded linux ( for GUI ) on top of that.

Comment: Which flavor of Linux are you running?

Comment: @David, added in Question.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought it was Montavista (saw you say that in Root Access) and I do not see anything in your question about Montavista. I added Montavista as a tag for your question.

Comment: @David. Montavista is a compamy that provides linux support.

Comment: Now I see... Sorry @SunnyShah. I was just trying to help with the information I knew. I went to Google and typed Montavista and one of the auto-completes was Montavista Linux download. Sorry for the confusion.